# SQL Having clause over filtering issue

Tags: mysql, sql, having

I need to get the students who get the highest total score in the table while there are more than one student getting the highest score. Why the result is different in the following 2 queries?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT SUM(points) total, student_id
FROM student_score_per_subject_table
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY 1 DESC
) students
HAVING total = MAX(total)
```

The result of this query has only one return and the student_id the alphabetically smallest one;

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT SUM(points) total, student_id
FROM student_score_per_subject_table
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY 1 DESC
) students
HAVING total = 100 -- highest total score
```

The result is desired with all highest-scorers being returned.

----- EDIT --------

MySQL version: 5.7.12

Comment: The first one performs **aggregation**. Since you do not have `GROUP BY` the result is a single row.

Comment: `HAVING total = MAX(total)` -- The query is malformed but MySQL 5.x runs it anyway. `total` should not be accepted by the query since it's not an aggregated expression; `MAX(total)` is OK.